# How do you get the value inside an XML document?

Tags: java, xml, selenium

In below XML I need to confirm "Internet" is there.

```
<section id="landing-content">
    <div id="header">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="span12">
                     <h1 class="theme--primary">Internet</h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

I tried the following:

```
WebElement findInternet = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1"));
System.out.println(findInternet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
WebElement findInternet = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1.theme--primary"));
System.out.println(findInternet.getText());
```

Your xpath selector will probably work as well, the key thing you were missing is your `println` was printing the `findInternet` object.  `getText()` will get the inner text of the selected element.`

Comment: Thank you very much.  Guess I need to brush up on my object oriented programming knowledge.  Been in VBscript QTP world for too long and now asked to tackle selenium with Java.